# Cannot use bigquery in appengine : "ImportError: No module named google.cloud.bigquery"

Tags: google-bigquery

Tried everything possible to fix this bug am not sure where I'm going wrong. I've run pip already and seems like everything is in place, but the lib errors are still there.

Need guidance on what else to check

```
pip install --system --upgrade -r requirements.txt -t lib
```

---

```
$ cat appengine_config.py
import sys    
import os
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
```

### vendor.add('lib')

```
$ cat requirements.txt 
GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient==1.9.22.1
google-api-python-client
google-cloud
google-cloud-bigquery
```

---

```
#Inside the code
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import Dataset
```

---

```
ERROR    2018-11-10 16:24:47,981 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/royans/repository/tesmon/tesmonweb/tmon.py", line 32, in <module>
from google.cloud import bigquery
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1149, in load_module
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
 ImportError: No module named google.cloud.bigquery
```

Comment: Is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/43085047/6253347

Comment: Try removing "google-cloud": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173371/no-module-named-google-cloud-helpers-on-gce/53181156#53181156

Comment: Unfortunately none of those options works. I was able to get the code running in the dev console itself... but after a couple of days that broke without any code changes. This whole thing seems fragile and its unfortunate that I don't know enough to debug this :(